# Replying to a reviewer - should use (Anonymous) if citing paper by co-author?

Tags: citations

I am writing the response to reviewers of a paper I submitted to a journal. This journal's policy is to cite papers by any author as "Anonymous, year". In one of the responses to the reviewer I want to mention that the only research that, to my knowledge, has been conducted on a point he brings up (he asks for me to cite any research on it) has been this paper by one of my co-authors. Should I cite it as "Anonymous" too?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to mention that the only research is by Smith (and it happens that Smith is one of your co-authors)? Or that the only research is by one of the authors of the current paper under review?

Comment: Also, you write that 'This journal's policy is to cite papers by any author as "Anonymous, year".' Do you mean that papers by any author *of the current work* should be cited this way, or papers by *any scientist*?

Comment: 1) The only research is done by Professor Smith, who is also featured as a co-author in the article under review (but I am the leading author).
2) Papers cited by an author of the current work, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Put yourself in the shoes of the reviewer, They may want to check that paper, having to search for it just by title (and finding out the author's name as a byproduct) just gives them a hard time. Or just say that the only work on the subject you are aware of is by the work group of the current authors.

Yes, "blind" review is often less than totally blind. It can't be, reviewers *do* work in the same (or nearby) area, and so know the say hundred or so researchers working on that topic, at least superficially.